# Translation Issue

Tags: magento2

I have created a `so_SO.csv` file for translation and extract data using 
`php bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases -o 'so_SO.csv ' -m` 
after that file has been translated with some extra keywords after that i have run this command 
`php bin/magento i18n:pack path to so_SO.csv  file -d so_SO` but file is not going in every module in magento.

But when i don't add any extra keyword it is working fine.
Can any one suggest me the solution.

Comment: can you share your code

Comment: i have follow only 2 commands Like on Magento Devdocs one is for phrase and other is for pack

Comment: how are you creating csv file using script or with other mehod?

Comment: using magento command bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases -o "/var/www/html/magento2/xx_YY.csv" -m